# What Series method replaced searchsorted?

Tags: python, pandas

In his video, [Data analysis in Python with pandas] (http://youtu.be/w26x-z-BdWQ?t=2h14s), Wes McKinney presents a series method names searchsorted(), which given a value, gives back the index in which the series is crossing that value. It appears this function is not available any more, did something else replace it?

Comment: Which video was this?

Comment: There is no `searchsorted` method in `Pandas`, there is one in numpy: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html, are you confusing it with this?

Comment: [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w26x-z-BdWQ) at 2:00:21 he uses `df.prop.cumsum().searchsorted` which seems to be a Series method.

Comment: This looks like something that has changed either since `Pandas 0.12` or `Numpy 1.6/1.7`, in `Pandas 0.13.1` you cannot do this anymore as you have found out, you would need to do `np.searchsorted(df.prop.cumsum().values, my_new_value)` which is not as elegant. This may be to do with Pandas Series now inherting from `NDFrame` rather than `ndarray` so you now lose this syntatic sugar

Comment: Definitely less elegant.. pitty

Comment: I have edited my answer you need to do this `df.prop.values.cumsum().searchsorted` not what I proposed earlier, I agree less elegant but there was a design decision behind all of this which will not have been made lightly

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe this is due to the refactoring that occurred in Pandas 0.13.0 where Pandas Series now sub-class NDFrame rather than ndarray see [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#internal-refactoring):

```
In [33]:

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':arange(10)})
df
Out[33]:

   a
0  0
1  1
2  2
3  3
4  4
5  5
6  6
7  7
8  8
9  9
```

[10 rows x 1 columns]

```
[10 rows x 3 columns]
In [28]:

# you now have to call `.values` to return a ndarray 
df.a.values.cumsum().searchsorted(11)
Out[28]:
5
```

Now compare what happens if we use a numpy array:

```
In [29]:

temp = np.array(arange(10))

In [32]:

temp.cumsum().searchsorted(11)
Out[32]:
5
```