# AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'searchsorted' pandas

Tags: python, pandas, series

I reproduce the code of book python for data analysis in page 38

I write

```
prop_cumsum = df.sort_index(by='prop', ascending=False).prop.cumsum()

and prop_cumsum.searchsorted(0.5)
```

Then there is an error say:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-f2e2bb3f5ba0> in <module>()
----> 1 prop_cumsum.searchsorted(0.5)

C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy32\User\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.pyc in __getattr__(self, name)
   1813                 return self[name]
   1814             raise AttributeError("'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" %
-> 1815                                  (type(self).__name__, name))
   1816 
   1817     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'searchsorted'
```

I can't understand why
i re-install numpy and lib pandas
it still can't work
It's no searchsorted methode in series in the document of pandas

In [49]:

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/lexual/pydata-book/blob/35fd20645c75128ae348a275848575e2eae7a025/ch02_us_baby_names.ipynb

Comment: Actually I answered this question a month ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21822988/what-series-method-replaced-searchsorted/21832478#21832478

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are probably using a version that is 0.13.0 or later where Series now subclasses `NDFrame`, you have to now do this to return a numpy array:

```
prop_cumsum.values.searchsorted(0.5)
```

as searchsorted is a numpy function and not a Pandas Series function.

See the [online docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#internal-refactoring)

Comment: Annoying that this doesn't work: np.searchsorted(prop_cumsum, 0.5)

Comment: @AndyHayden yes I agree it would be nice to be able to achieve this

Comment: I that is another case of numpy not calling ``__array__`` properly

Comment: @EdChum I don't see a problem with actually defining ``searchsorted`` on a Series btw (and then in theory could properly handle dtypes, e.g. datetime64[ns]``, want to do a PR? (and it would return the index, rather than the indicies; as an aside also easy to auto-sort this too, e.g. check ``Series.index.is_monotonic``)

Comment: @Jeff Do we have an issue to keep track of all places where numpy does that?

Comment: not really, maybe create one, to my knowledge, np.sort (see here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6539), np.where, np.ones_like, np.zero_like, np.searchsorted....