# Numpy's searchsorted() cannot be used with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm learning data science with "**Python for Data Analysis**" book. 
In the book, the author uses `.searchsorted()` from `numpy` but it seems like it's not working with a particular code that the author gives us.

I have a `dataframe` and I want to find the number in the list with a specific figure.

The author's code is this:

```
df = boys[boys.year == 2010]
prop_cumsum = df.sort_index(by='prop', ascending=False).prop.cumsum()
prop_cumsum.searchsorted(0.5)
```

But it gives an error saying:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'searchsorted'
```

The code below works but it gives me unwanted figures as well:

```
np.searchsorted(prop_cumsum,0.5)

Out[13]: 
year  sex       
1900  M    54492    24
           54493    24
           54494    24
           54495    24
           54496    24
           54497    24
           54498    24
           54499    24
           54500    24
           54501    24
           54502    24
           54503    24
           54504    24
           54505    24
           54506    24
...
1900  M    55508    24
           55509    24
           55510    24
           55511    24
           55505    24
           55513    24
           55514    24
           55515    24
           55516    24
           55517    24
           55520    24
           55518    24
           55512    24
           55519    24
           55524    24
Name: prop, Length: 1000, dtype: int64
```

Based on the book, I should expect an output like:

```
In [399]: prop_cumsum.searchsorted(0.5) + 1
Out[399]: 25
```

Comment: Are you using the same version as your author's? Like the 2.x series?

Comment: HOw boys looks like/or was generated?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What Series method replaced searchsorted?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21822988/what-series-method-replaced-searchsorted)

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're working with Pandas >= 0.13.0

From this version and on, Pandas `series` subclasses numpy's `ndframe` and no more `ndarray`. [See here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#internal-refactoring) for more information.

You can now use `.values` to return a `ndarray` upon which you can call `searchsorted`.

```
df = boys[boys.year == 2010]
prop_cumsum = df.sort_index(by='prop', ascending=False).prop.values.cumsum()
prop_cumsum.searchsorted(0.5)                               ^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. Not sure why O'Reilly isn't adding this to the errata for the book. http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=0636920023784